# CSS: IE11 not applying style

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

At [this page](https://www.orsgroup.com.au/about/) there is a graphic in the sidebar:

[image]

I have in the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE]>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen" />

<![endif]-->
```

The `ie.css` file contains `.textwidget {display: inline-block;}` however **this CSS rule is not being applied** when I select the `<div class="textwidget">` while inspecting the graphic **in IE11**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE11 doesn't support conditional comments such as `<!--[if IE]>`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Important** As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't supported by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `type` of the `link` you are adding. It should be

```
<!--[if IE]>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made the changed, uploaded, cleared server and browser cache. but `.textwidget {display: inline-block;}` inside `https://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/themes/nevada-child/css/ie.css` is not being applied.

Comment: Did you implemented that on the live link? I cant see any changes at my end.